# Vercel Deployment Error: @notionhq/client warn: request fail { code: 'unauthorized', message: 'API token is invalid.' }

Tags: vercel

when I deployment a Project in vercel.com, I got this error:

The crux of the matter is "request fail { code: 'unauthorized', message: 'API token is invalid.' }", it results in an unsuccessful deployment

```
Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
https://nextjs.org/telemetry
info  - Checking validity of types...
info  - Creating an optimized production build...
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data...
@notionhq/client warn: request fail { code: 'unauthorized', message: 'API token is invalid.' }
> Build error occurred
Error [APIResponseError]: API token is invalid.
    at buildRequestError (/vercel/path0/node_modules/.pnpm/@notionhq+client@1.0.4/node_modules/@notionhq/client/build/src/errors.js:162:16)
    at Client.request (/vercel/path0/node_modules/.pnpm/@notionhq+client@1.0.4/node_modules/@notionhq/client/build/src/Client.js:304:54)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async getDatabase (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/312.js:49:22)
    at async getStaticPaths (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/blog/[slug].js:880:16)
    at async buildStaticPaths (/vercel/path0/node_modules/.pnpm/next@12.1.6_ef5jwxihqo6n7gxfmzogljlgcm/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:491:31)
    at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/.pnpm/next@12.1.6_ef5jwxihqo6n7gxfmzogljlgcm/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:632:119
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/.pnpm/next@12.1.6_ef5jwxihqo6n7gxfmzogljlgcm/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20) {
  type: 'APIResponseError',
  code: 'unauthorized',
  status: 401,
  headers: {},
  body: '{"object":"error","status":401,"code":"unauthorized","message":"API token is invalid."}'
}
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
Error! Command "pnpm run build" exited with 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the question! It seems like you didn't setup your env variables through vercel's dashboard